# Selenium unknown error: unhandled inspector error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am receiving following error while executing the line(`selenium chrome driver`):

```
driver.findElements(By.className("myClass"));
```

> unknown error: unhandled inspector error: `{"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot find execution context with given id"}`

What is the reason for this error? How can i solve it?

Comment: seems like there is an issue with identification of inspector, can you share the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it is due to a bug. See:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1238

for more information.

I had the same problem. It disappeared after upgrading to version 2.21:

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.21/

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue today exclusively with ChromeDriver on a project that has been working fine. I found that upgrading to the following version of ChromeDriver fixed the issue for me:

[ChromeDriver v2.21 Download Page](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.21/)

Answer (score 4):

The problem also affected me when I was trying to click on an element which was in the default content and I was on an iFrame.

Adding the following code solved it for me:

```java
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue it's due to being on the wrong frame.  Switch back to the root frame (Default Frame) and you'll be fine